# Out of memory when using multiple GPUs with larger batch_size in Caffe

Tags: neural-network, gpu, caffe, multi-gpu

I am now fine-tuning on [VGG-Face](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/vgg_face/) (very big model) with 8 TITAN Xp GPUs available. However, Caffe gives out-of-memory error when I increase  `batch_size`. Here is what I did:

First, `batch_size` was set to 40 for training stage and it works fine on a single GPU. The chosen GPU was nearly 100% utilized.
Then, I increased `batch_size` to 128 with all the 8 GPUs using

```
'./build/tools/caffe train -solver mysolver.prototxt -gpu all'
```

All the GPUs were fully utilized, as is shown in [nvidia-smi.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNA89.png)

And Caffe gives me the following error:

```
F0906 03:41:32.776806 95655 parallel.cpp:90] Check failed: error ==cudaSuccess (2 vs. 0)  out of memory
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
@     0x7f9a0832995d  google::LogMessage::Fail()
@     0x7f9a0832b6e0  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
@     0x7f9a08329543  google::LogMessage::Flush()
@     0x7f9a0832c0ae  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
@     0x7f9a08abe825  caffe::GPUParams<>::GPUParams()
@     0x7f9a08abefd8  caffe::NCCL<>::NCCL()
@           0x40dc69  train()
@           0x40a8ed  main
@     0x7f9a06abf830  (unknown)
@           0x40b349  _start
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Theoretically I can train with the `batch_size=40*8=320`. (Please let me know if I am right here)

So, how can I fully utilized the GPUs to accelerate my model training?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When using multiple GPUs, you don't need to increase the batch size in your prototxt. If your batch size was 40, Caffe will use that size for each GPU individually, thus effectively giving you a batch size of 40*8 (without you having to change anything).

Comment: Then, what about TESTING? If I have 8 GPUs, which one will be used for testing?

Comment: @Y.C.Sun I believe the default 0 GPU would be used, unless you explicitly specify which one to use.

Comment: One more confusion. If batch size is 40 and 8 GPUs are used, is the gradient computed by averaging the 320 samples together OR averaging the 8 individually averaged gradients from every 40 samples?

Comment: The gradients are shared in a tree like topology. So GPU number 0 and 1 will share gradients (and they'll be averaged), GPU 2 and 3 will share, and then these two averaged gradients will again be averaged. (Simplifying the case by taking 4 GPUs)

Comment: Got it! Moreover, suppose the training set has 100 samples and I want to train for 10 epochs with 2 GPUs, should the max_iter be set to 10*100/batch_size or 10*100/batch_size/2?

Comment: The latter I guess :)

Comment: Thx for your answer!

Comment: Also, averaging is linear, so it shouldn't matter (right?)